# Getting data from json file for D3 bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a bubble chart based on the example from the d3 wiki. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

Unfortunately I'm still at the beginner level of javascript and don't understand some of the code.

The layout of json is here: http://pastebin.com/QAMBfLjr

I want to create circles and name them after the value and have their size be based on count.

It seems the piece of code I need to modify is this:

```
function recurse(name, node) {
  if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
  else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
}
```

So I'm substituting instances of children for the path to what I want to iterate over in the json. Then I change the name of the keys I want.

```
facet_counts.facet_pivot["category_level0,category_level1,category_level2,category_level3"]
```

So that piece of code looks like:

```
function recurse(name, node) {
  if (node.facet_counts.facet_pivot["category_level0,category_level1,category_level2,category_level3"]) node.facet_counts.facet_pivot["category_level0,category_level1,category_level2,category_level3"].forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.value, child); });
  else classes.push({packageName: value, className: node.value, value: node.count});
}
```

But that's not working. I don't see anything on the page and the console output says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'facet_pivot' of undefined
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**Adding jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwhite/4o6tbe0w/**

Comment: Are you passing in the correct json file in this line?

Comment: d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root)

Comment: Adding a fiddle would be helpful also... https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The example code only uses that `recurse` function to flatten the `flare.json` data (which is a nested structure).  Your structure already looks pretty flat and you just use `json["facet_counts"]["facet_pivot"]["category_level0,category_level1,category_level2,category_level3"]`

Comment: I've added a fiddle. @brettwgreen I named my json file the same thing so I don't need to change the name there. Mark - I see what you're saying. I thought I needed to recurse to go down into multiple levels.

Comment: fiddle is unable to load the file flare.json

Comment: I would just include it inline

Comment: @brettwgreen I've updated the fiddle with the data inline. When I run this I get two console errors: 
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"
d3.v3.min.js:1 
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute r="NaN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out. I didn't see that the json file I'm using is in a different format from the one that is supplied with the example.

After playing around a bit in the dev console I figured out I had to edit the processData function to the following:

```
        function processData(data) { 
          var obj = data.facet_counts.facet_pivot["category_level0,category_level1,category_level2,category_level3"];
          var newDataSet = [];

          for(var prop in obj) {
            newDataSet.push({name: obj[prop].value, className: obj[prop].value.toLowerCase(), size: obj[prop].count}); 
        }
        return {children: newDataSet}; 
    }
```